# Logic Apps - "Authorization Failed - The authentication credentials are not valid"

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app that I can call successfully using any rest client, but when my application tries to call it I get a `401`

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization Failed",
        "message": "The authentication credentials are not valid"
    }
}
```

The trigger is an http request and I am using the exact one copied from the Logic App.

Any ideas how I can see the failed connection attempts in Logic Apps so I can troubleshoot further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any ideas how I can see the failed connection attempts in Logic Apps so I can troubleshoot further?

According to your description, I suggest you could provide more details and code about how you call logic apps from your application.  There are many causes about 401 error. You could check your username, password and  related authentication code in application.  Or you could set a break point to debug in your application.

Besides, there are some ways you could troubleshoot in logic apps:

1. See  outputs link in Trigger History. You could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-diagnosing-failures).
2. Open the diagnostic logs in logic apps. You can monitor logic apps and store related records of logs. The failed records also in it. You could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-monitor-your-logic-apps).
   [image]
3. Monitor and get insights about logic app runs with Operations Management Suite (OMS) and Log Analytics. You could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-monitor-your-logic-apps-oms).